# Jquery/Javascript : Selector in jquery is not working if the element is inside a table <td>

Tags: jquery

Can you help me explain what is happening  between my jquery and table? I have the code here:

```
<table class="table table-responsive" id="student-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
        <td>{{student.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{student.age}}</td>
        <td>{{student.address}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-button" > Delete </button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

my javascript code is :

```
$('#delete-button').on('click', function() {

    console.log('delete btn clicked!');

});
```

This code above will not work BUT if i put my Delete btn outside the TABLE the button is now responding when i click it. How does that happen and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**: Duplicate IDs.

When there are duplicate ID's the script will work only on the first element with given id parsing from the top of the HTML. If you test it right you can see it working only for your first row delete button.

**Solution**: replace your Id with `class` and use this class in your selector ..

`<button class="btn btn-danger delete-button" >`

`$('.delete-button').on('click'....`